# Getting error when trying to export MariaDB service with MySQL Workbench

Tags: swisscomdev

We used to use a service key to connect to the MariaDB service with MySQL Workbench for creating local backups,doing smaller data maintenance, comparing data with other instances (not necessarily on CloudFoundry etc.).

This works perfectly by opening a local connection with `cf ssh` and using the parameters from a service key.

Formerly we were able to create a self-contained export file from the database, but now I am getting the following error:

> Unhandled exception: Error querying security information: Error executing 'SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE User='myuser' AND Host='127.0.0.1' ORDER BY User, Host'
>   SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'yourIP' for table 'user'.
>   SQL Error: 1142

How to achieve a simple *.sql backup from one database service nowadays - ideally without additional proxy apps etc?

**UPDATE**

Tried DBeaver now, which produces the following command:

`/usr/bin/mysqldump --routines --add-drop-table --disable-keys --extended-insert -v --host=127.0.0.1 --port=13003 -u myuser mydb`

Results in

> Access denied for user 'myuser'@'10.0.20.44'

There's no difference when I provide a password directly with --password=mypassword

Alternatives mentioned in the docs don't seem to offer what we're looking for (simple full .sql export from database)

Comment: MariaDB is incompatible to Oracle MySQL in recent versions. I can't query mysql.user as normal user `ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user`. It's easiest when you search for an Alternative to MySQL Workbench (Oracle) https://alternativeto.net/software/mysql-workbench/. In the official docs we recommend some tools https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-offerings/mariadb.html#administrating

Comment: thanks, was looking for an alternative @fyodor-glebov, question updated

Comment: create a new service key and/or binding. If this doesn't work please upen up a support ticket with Org/Space and Service GUID. For me the DBeaver mysqldump command works (as unprivileged user) fine `-- Dump completed on 2018-03-12 14:46:44`

Answer (score 0):

The error states what the problem is: `SELECT command denied to user 'myuser'@'yourIP' for table 'user'.`

Try granting the SELECT privilege on that table to the user you were using:

```
GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO 'myuser'@'yourIP';
```

Comment: it's a shared db cluster - if I'd be able to grant myself permission on the main user table would be a huge issue. i don't understand why a select on the user table is necessary in this cast at all.

Comment: Perhaps some stored procedures or functions cause that grant to be required. If there are no good reasons to require SELECT on `mysql.user` then I'd recommend opening a bug report on the MariaDB Jira: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV